# Python does not import installed external library

Tags: python, import, anaconda, spyder, ta-lib

This is a rather weird problem. I'm on `Windows` and using `Anaconda` for `Python`. There is a financial tool library called `TA_lib` (Technical Analysis Library). Since this library is not officially supported, I had to install a `whl` version and I got it from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

After installation I was able to use it. But sometimes, when I start `Anaconda` and `Spyder`, the import talib command yields `"Talib has no functiona as ..."` and I cannot import and use it. When this happens, I follow these steps:

1. I close Anaconda and Spyder
2. I install the library again through Anaconda prompt (I see requirement already satisfied messge)
3. I restart Anaconda and Spyder

If I'm lucky, I can import `talib` after first try. If not, I have to repeat these steps for a couple of times. What might be wrong?

EDIT 1:

Now it's not working. Here is the error log:

```
import pandas as pd
import talib
import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-a3bb601353da>", line 2, in <module>
    import talib

  File "C:\Users\ismetb\Desktop\AlgoritmikFinans\Classifier 11-12-2018 1830 v2\talib.py", line 90, in <module>
    upperband, middleband, lowerband = talib.BBANDS(close, timeperiod=5, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=talib.MA_Type.T3)

AttributeError: module 'talib' has no attribute 'BBANDS'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you've installed it wrong. Also consider that this is an unofficial library.

Make sure you installed the correct TA_lib for your Python version. What Python version are you using? 
If it's 3.4, make sure you have downloaded the [TA_lib cp34](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib) for windows 64 bits or 32 bits. If it's another version, make sure you find the one appropriate to you.

Also another useful link to download TA_lib for 64bit is  [here](https://github.com/afnhsn/TA-Lib_x64).

Comment: I believe I did not install it wrong since I've been using it for a long time. But, not always :) I am using the library but sometimes I cannot import it. That's my problem. All version, bit etc controls are OK.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem. My `Python` file name was `Talib_pure` and then I renamed it to `Talib`. Since I import `talib` with `import talib` command, `Python` tried to import my own code isntead of `talib` library and therefore it got confused.

I renamed the file to `ta_lib` and now it works (so far at least).